# Functional equation and Riemann function $ \xi(s) $

Tags: functional-equations

Is there any theorem or proof that if a function satisfy the functional equation $ f(1-s)=f(s)$ and $ f(s) >0$ for each real $s$ then $ f(s)= \xi(s)$ or $ f(s)= \operatorname{const}$?

Comment: Did you mean to say $f(s) = \kappa \cdot \xi(s)$ for some $\kappa > 0$ ?

Comment: aha.. considering $ f(s)$ is positive and differentiable for each real number , so we avoid the solutions similar to $ |s(1-s)| $

Comment: False.  Try $f(s) = \cos(2\pi s) + 2$.

Comment: Or, more simply, $f(s) = (s(1-s))^2 + 1$. You should look up Hamburger's theorem if you're trying to find conditions under which the completed zeta-function is characterized up to a scaling factor.

Comment: where can i find hamburguers theorem ??

Comment: Did you try an internet search?? Lots of hits come up. Here is one link: pages 127-129 at http://hh-mouvement.com.pagesperso-orange.fr/seminario0.pdf.

Comment: Slightly tangential: Isn't the Riemann function denoted $\zeta(x)$ ("zeta"), not $\xi(x)$ ("xi")?
Edit: Okay, I read http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Xi-Function.html. I learned something new today! Yay!

Answer (score 2):

If $f(s)$ is a solution then so is $f^2$ or $e^f$ or $H(f(s))$ for any positivity-preserving function $H$.  The functional equation alone does not characterize the (completed) zeta function up to a finite number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The question is wrong.

In fact for the functional equation $f(1-s)=f(s)$, its general solution, according to http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fe/fe1113.pdf, should be $f(s)=\Phi(s,1-s)$, where $\Phi(s,1-s)$ is any symmetric function of $s$ and $1-s$.

And also there are infintely many $\Phi(s,1-s)$ satisfly $\Phi(s,1-s)>0$ for each real $s$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(z):=f(s)=f((1/2)+iz)$.
Then we have
$$f(1-s)=f((1/2)- iz)=g(-z)\tag{1}$$
$$f(s)=f((1/2)+ iz)=g(z)\tag{2}$$

Using functional equation, we have:

$$g(-z)=f(1-s)=f(s)=g(z)\tag{3}$$.

Thus as long as $g(z)$ is an even function of $z$, $f(s)=g(-is-1/2)$ will satisfy the functional equation $f(s)=f(1-s)$.